# A Christmas tree has the shape of the conical helix. Find the length of the Christmas tree.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A Christmas tree has the shape of the conical helix. The helix has the circular base of 1 foot diameter, 
and it rises three complete turns. Find the length of the Christmas tree.

[Image the goes with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmn5S.png)

Please explain the steps. Thanks!

Comment: At this point I am completely lost. Not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start: a (cylindrical) helix could be written as $x(t) = \cos t$, $y(t) = \sin t$, $z(t) = t$.  You should check that this helix actually lies on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  We want to modify this so that the helix instead lies on the cone $(1-z)^2 = x^2 + y^2$.  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(z-1)%5E2+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2), your "tree" should lie on the portion of this cone between $z=0$ and $z=1$.

We can modify so that the helix lies on the cone: $x(t) = (1-t)\cos t$, $y(t) = (1-t)\sin t$, $z(t) = t$, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.  You should check that this actually lies on the cone.  However, it does not make three rotations from $0$ to $1$.  We can adjust this by adjusting the arguments inside cosine and sine, since these affect the speed of the rotation:

$$x(t) = (1-t)\cos(6\pi t),$$
$$y(t) = (1-t)\sin(6\pi t),$$
$$z(t) = t,$$
$$ 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$

You should make sure you understand why this lies on the cone, and why it makes three rotations from $t=0$ to $t=1$.  (See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7B(1-t)cos(6Pi*t),(1-t)sin(6Pi*t),t%7D,%7Bt,+0,++1%7D%5D) to visualize).

Now all that's left is to compute the arc length of this curve, which you can do with the formula:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2} \ dt.$$